# Less formal synonym for interlocutor

Tags: synonyms

I need a noun to describe a person taking part in a chat conversation. Using dictionary I found `interlocutor`, but it is so rare and formal.

Comment: When you say *chat* are you referring to the chat section of Stack Exchange or a similar site?

Comment: @Jason Bassford Yes, a chat for a web service

Comment: **chat partner** might do.

Comment: Any suggestions with `co-`?

Comment: [Synonym](https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/interlocutor) is the best choice for words with similar meaning questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only word in English I can think of that's synonymous with the word *interlocutor* would be [**conversational partner**](https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/conversational-partner) (that's more like a compound noun, actually, rather than a word) as there are really no other simple, daily words for that idea. But whether *conversational partner* will suit your needs largely depends on the context you're going to use it in. It'd be great if you could provide an example sentence with a series of blanks for the missing word. Normally, though, you would probably describe that kind of person as just **the person you're speaking with** or as **the person you're having a conversation with**.

If you're talking about things like Internet chat rooms, then one simple way to refer to the person you're chatting with would be **your chat partner**.

Answer (score 2):

As clarified in a comment to the question, this is related to chat groups similar to those here on Stack Exchange.

A common word would be a (chat) **participant**. (Simply "[one that participates](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/participant).")

Its use is not restricted to people on chat groups (or even people talking)—but *interlocutor* is also used in more contexts than just chat groups.