# How to say in one word "the one who you talk with"?

Tags: word-choice

Google translate says it's "interlocutor". But I've never heard of it before. I suspect it is a very formal word (used in the legal etc.). FWIW, in Russian there is a pretty common word "собеседник" (sobesednik) used both in formal and informal speech.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no less formal, one-word expression in English that expresses that idea. However, some time ago, we had a similar question posted here on ELL where I suggested the phrase **conversation partner**. If you're interested, by all means go ahead a take a look at that post: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/185404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a similar question on this forum of the StackExchange: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296995/how-can-you-say-the-person-im-talking-with-with-one-word

Interlocutor sounds formal, and it actually is used in a formal context, among its other usages (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlocutor))As far as most thesauruses go, there is no 'everyday usage' synonym for interlocutor, which is the closest word to what you might have in mind. If you don't want to use 'interlocutor', you might have to resort to words which are very close in meaning.

I checked Google Translate as well for your provided word, just to get a little idea of the context it is used in, and looked up synonyms on the various reference sites. [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/interlocutor) provides a few synonyms which are near, but not *quite* there. 'Conversationalist' or 'conversational partner' come pretty close in meaning, but I feel those aren't simpler than 'interlocutor'. Even [Context Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/russian-english/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) suggests words like 'companion' or 'conversationalist'.

So, in short, there is no exact simple word that might suit the phrase you have in mind. You'll need to resort to alternatives to put across your meaning. I hope that answers your question (even though I couldn't give you a perfect solution).